# Convert point shapefile to polygon with QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am new to using QGIS. I have a point shapefile that I would like to convert to a polygon. I followed the directions for using point2one plugin but got this: [image].

This is what I want: [image]

My attribute table has fields for ID, latitude,longitude, tracts, order(a field I created to group the IDs by tracts.

Comment: Have you tried the answers in this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189446/drawing-outline-of-point-cloud-using-qgis?

Comment: Thank you @ahmadhanb, I just tried it and it worked. However, I lost all the observations, When I import the new shapefile into Geoda, It shows just one observation. I had 360 in the points shapefile.

Comment: A polygon is composed of an ordered list of vertices. If your vertices are unordered, then you can't use a library function which requires order. While it is possible to associate the point records with the polygon, a single feature only has one row in the resulting data table.

Comment: Thank @Vince. What do you suggest I do? I created an order field, but I guess I did it wrongly!

Comment: @Anwuli-Mich : sorry to say but u don't define "what u want" ... even if your points get ordered i don't see how u can obtain your green polygon ... Did u check "**convex hull**" ? seeing your example it doesn't seem to be the right answer either ...