# Minimum enclosing polygons for point clusters

Tags: qgis, python, point, clustering, polyline-creation

I am trying to find an algorithm that can create minimum enclosing polygons from a set of points. The existing algorithms such as. Convex Hull, Concave Hull (both Alpha shapes and K nearest Neighbors), Delaunay Triangulations do not work well for some of the point clusters as shown in the image. Existing algorithms in the Processing Toolbox do not work for the sample data that I have attached.

Another suggestion was to use "Points to Path" algorithm and convert the results to Polygon. That works only if the points are in order. For point groups created using clustering, this doesn't work.

[image]

Would prefer a QGIS or Python solution.

Link to sample data [points.gpkg](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1P6HKtqn_bcFJnBbfOcuYTjM6OF3NekPA)

Comment: I think you also forget to mention the ["Concave hull (alpha shapes)"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#concave-hull-alpha-shapes) and the ["Concave hull (k-nearest neighbor)"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#concave-hull-k-nearest-neighbor), did not you? Check this thread: [Creating polygon around set of points using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395831/creating-polygon-around-set-of-points-using-pyqgis).

Comment: for python, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57378168/9326457 https://pypi.org/project/alphashape/

Comment: I tried both alpha shapes and k-nearet neighbors, but the result is still not ideal (it gives the same as convex gull). I did a batch process with multiple parameters but none give the result as the 'desired polygon'. Updated the question with a link to the sample data.